# Facebook hide content from non-fans in a unique way

Tags: facebook, tabs, hide

I need to build a tab looking like this one: 
https://www.facebook.com/auto.co.il/app_134594493332806

I know how to add an image and a comment box and i know of several "plain" ways to hide the content from non-fans, but i came across the above tab and i really like the way it shows thee content yet you cant engage it until you press the like button.

Any help please?

Thanks in advance.

Oren

Answer (score 0):

Your link didn't work for me, but you can place a absolutely positioned div with a high z-index above the rest of your content to prevent the user from clicking on anything.

**Update:** Now that the link has been updated I see that they are doing exactly what I described above. In chrome if you right-click the background and select "inspect element" you will see the following computed style for the div:

```
rgba(0,0,0,0.796);
display:block;
height:1612px;
width:810px;
```

The content is blacked out simply with a div with a black background and some opacity. Just for fun, you can overcome their like gate (without liking) via chrome's JS console by selecting the iframe context and then entering the following:

`$('.like_float_c').detach();`

... now call youself a 'hacker' ;)

Comment: Hi Gil & thanks for your reply. i've changed the link - does it work now?